# Multiple Method Parameters for Role Selection Recommendations

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

My current method:

```
    public static IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> GetListByRole(string role)
    {
        using (AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext())
        {
            return db.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.Role.Name == role) && u.DateDeleted == null).ToList<ApplicationUser>();
        }
    }
```

I would like to be able to do `GetListByRole("Admin", "User")` or `GetListByRole("Admin")`.

What is the best way to structure a methods parameters to do this?  Do I use a string[]?  If so, how would I change the LINQ query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Contains` method:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> GetListByRole(params string[] roles)
{
    using (AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext())
    {
        return db.Users
                .Where(u => roles.Contains(u.Role.Name) && 
                       u.DateDeleted == null)
                .ToList<ApplicationUser>();
    }
}
```

[`params keyword`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) allows you to pass role names without creating array explicitly.But you should be aware of that it also allows you to pass `0` parameter..

Comment: Thanks!  What does the 'params' keyword do/mean?

Comment: Ok. In my example above, u.Roles is an ICollection and you used it like it was a single object.  Any thoughts?